# Ajax: why does ajax keeps running when i deleted its script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have downloaded a source code about live search using ajax.
so it has a a file of `custom.js`, `search.html`, and `search.php` .

so iv'e been trying to modify it to meet my needs but as i tried editing or deleting all the codes inside `custom.js` where the ajax scripts in and saved it and refresh the browser, it still runs the ajax script as i was not edited or deleted. iv'e tried closing the browser and tried it again and it keeps running like theirs no edit happened.

does anyone why this keeps happening?. i can't modify the custom.js coz i wont know if my edits works.

here's the code inside the `custom.js`

/* JS File */

```
// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#result-here").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: actually, this is supposed to be a caching-problem. so first of all: which browser do you use? Then: Have you tried disabling cache(s) via developer tools (e.g. chrome: f12 / cmd+alt+i -> network-tab -> disable cache) of your browser? OR pressing strg +f5 / cmd + shift + r instead of only trying to reload normally? OR do I understand you correctly and you are trying to change the js directly in the browser devtools? So, there MIGHT be a little chance it has something to do with your code, but to know what happens, we have to see the "old" code and the "new" one after editing.

Comment: Im using chrome. and its works when i press f12 and disable the cache. thanks men. it just saving the script in a cache due to the ajax code im i right?

Comment: I made an answer out of the comment. Hope you'll accept :) sure, it just saves the javascript (the part which gets executed in the browser). If you change something server-side (at your ajax-endpoint), you're not messing with caches (apart from working with damn ugly frameworks such as sharepoint or such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for it was actually the answer, I'll post a version of my comment here, too:

actually, this is supposed to be a caching-problem. so

first of all: which browser do you use?

Then: One possible solution is disabling the browser-cache. Have you tried disabling cache(s) via developer tools (e.g. chrome: f12 / cmd+alt+i -> network-tab -> disable cache) of your browser?

(as the above was the answer here, the *italics*-text just stays as an advise for people not getting it to work):

*OR did you try pressing `strg +f5` / `cmd + shift + r` instead of only trying to reload normally?*

*OR do I understand you correctly and you are trying to change the js directly in the browser devtools?*

*So, there MIGHT be a little chance it has something to do with your code, but to know what happens, we have to see the "old" code and the "new" one after editing.*

... apart from that, what Sagar Arora suggests in his/her answer is something called a cache-safe token, which would definitely get you around the problem, too, because for every request, you'll load not just 'custom.js', which then gets cached, but 'custom.js?v=x', where x is the cache-safe token (should be longer than from 1 to 10, though ;) )

Answer (score 1):

This is the caching problem. 
Open inspector and check "Disable cache"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrXNh.png)
*This option is only work when you open inspector so keep it's opened when you debug*

Comment: you have same answer as the comment and it works. And also thanks for answering =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that browser is detecting that same custom.js file is called every time.

In your search.php file where you have called the custom.js file just change your custom.js to load with some dynamic version change every time page loads.

Like this

```
From: <script src="custom.js"></script> 
To  : <script src="custom.js?v="<?php echo rand(0,9); ?>></script>
```

This will definitely solve your problem.